# Valid out-of-state DMV driver's license but class 7, moving from British Columbia to Washington

Tags: driving-license

I just moved to Seattle from British Columbia, Canada and I have my class 7 license. According to dmv.com, "If you have a valid out-of-state DMV driver’s license, you will not be required to pass any additional tests." I have also heard that if you are over 18 and have two years of driving experience, you do not need to take any tests. Does this only apply to a full license? Or does it apply to someone who is over 18, has their class 7, and has two years of driving experience?

Comment: Can you explain what a "class 7" license is for those of us who aren't from BC?

Comment: Of course! A class 7 license refers to the "novice (N) stage" of driving in BC. When someone has their class 7/N, they can drive alone, but have a few restrictions. In BC, there are 3 stages. First, one will take a knowledge test to get their Learners and one year after that, they can take a road test to get their class 7/N (2nd Stage). After two years of having a class 7/N, another road test is taken to get a class 5 license (3rd Stage).